# Tinymce editor is not displaying in some textareas

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce

I have a certain code to display some `textarea` according to the number of days choosed, i need all these text areas as editor .I have given then class `tinyMCE` but its not working

Its working if i use html code directly .Im using `jquery html()` to display contents and while using this the editor is not showing

```
division +='<div class="form-group">Activity on '
           +btwn[i].getDate()+' '+month+
           '<div id="activity_div"><input type="hidden" name="hidden_date[]" value="'+btwn[i].getDate()+
           '"/><input type="hidden" name="hidden_day[]" value="'+month+
           '"/><label for="input-demo-a-1">Activity name</label><input type="text" id="test-text'+i+
           '" name="activity_name[]" style="width:99.5%;"/></br><label for="input-demo-a-1">Activity detail</label><textarea id="test2-text'+i+
           '" class="tinyMCE " name="activity_detail[]" style="width:99.5%;"></textarea></br><button  class="btn btn-success actvty" id="actvty-btn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#long-modal'+i+
           '" rel="'+i+'">Load Activities<input type="hidden" name="n_days" value="'+d+
           '"/></div></div>'
```

`division` is the content I'm using and display it using `$("#my_testing").html(division);`

The editor is not showing while using this method , please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After adding the `textarea` dynamically you need to re-init the tinymce so it will apply to the new textareas:

```
tinymce.init({selector:'.tinyMCE'});
```

Comment: Your welcome @freelancephinix, hope it works. If so, you can either upvote and or accept the answer so other people know it worked.